# What will 'Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86' return on 32 bit Windows OS?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

I have an application which should spawn a 32 bit CMD process.

```
bool is64BitOS = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;
Environment.SpecialFolder systemFolder = is64BitOS ? Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86 : 
Environment.SpecialFolder.System;
processName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(systemFolder),"cmd.exe");
```

I was wondering whether I need to check for OS bitness to handle the differences between 64 bit and 32 bit Windows CMD path
or
Will 'Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86' handle the differences and I do not have to worry about it?

PS: My application is compiled with 'AnyCPU' target platform

Comment: It is a good question that I do not know the answer to. With Unix implementations of .NET, both folders may be `""`. [Try it online! (source code encoded in URL)](https://tio.run/##rY3BCoJAFEX3fsXgShe5CgnETVIRFAZCtR3Ghz0Y38i8SYjw2yfBIlq5aXvvPecqXihW3t8ZqRHVgx20WcBOOlRCacksiuD5CXqDtThKpCgew8IQGw3JxaKDAxJEG@rRGmqBXLLndLlGV3ZgR5aayR1nM1hZncEyGppd7sBtja7BnqS7/TRVBwqlntrkfSzyXIThn63XVfoVD8Hg/Qs "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: Why do you care about the *terminal's* bitness? You don't need `cmd` at all to spawn any process, just use `Process.Start` with the path to the executable. All examples that show calling `cmd` and passing the executable as an argument are simply wrong, unless they intended to explicitly create a terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 32-bit system, you'll get back the same value as you get for `SpecialFolder.System`, so no, this isn't necessary. You can use `SpecialFolder.SystemX86` to unambiguously get the system folder containing 32-bit binaries.

Source: `Environment.GetFolderPath` delegates to `SHGetFolderPath`, with `SpecialFolder.SystemX86` mapping to `CSIDL_SYSTEMX86`, which is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid#remarks) to map to `%windir%\system32` on 32-bit systems. This value was introduced in Windows 2000, so unless you're planning to run on a *very* old and unsupported version of Windows (with an equally ancient version of .NET) there's no need to check.

Note that the results depend only on the bitness of your OS, not the bitness of your process; 32-bit and 64-bit processes will get back the same values (but, of course, file system redirection means 32-bit processes usually access `SysWOW64` under the hood when they access `System32`).